# Register Form not saving to database: Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, view, models

*Weird issue with by registration form, not sure i am doing wrong.*

I have `StudentProfile` Model, that I am trying to save data from `StudentResistrationForm` but the **data is not being saved into database**

> ERROR: NameError at /register/ name 'StudentProfile' is not defined

***Is the view logic correct? What am I missing? Ideas please***

model

```
class Accounts(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('first name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField('last name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('date joined', auto_now_add=True)

    # asdd
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('Accounts', related_name='student_profile')
    # additional fields for students
    AMEB_Ratings = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
```

form

```
class StudentResistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentProfile
        fields = (  
            'AMEB_Ratings',

        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(StudentResistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        # user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        # user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.AMEB_Ratings = self.cleaned_data['AMEB_Ratings']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user 

    class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = get_user_model()
            fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

view

```
def registerStudent(request):
    # Once register page loads, either it will send to the server POST data (if the form is submitted), else if it don't send post data create a user form to register
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        form = StudentResistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
            User = get_user_model()
            username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = user_form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = user_form.cleaned_data['password']
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)

            Student_profile = StudentProfile()
            Student_profile.user = new_user
            Student_profile.AMEB_Ratings = request.POST['AMEB_Ratings']
            # Student_profile = StudentProfile.create_user(AMEB_Ratings=AMEB_Ratings)
            new_user.save()
            Student_profile.save()
            # form.save()

            # AMEB_Ratings = form.cleaned_data['AMEB_Ratings']
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        #  Create the django default user form and send it as a dictionary in args to the reg_form.html page.
        user_form = UserForm()
        form = StudentResistrationForm()        

        # args = {'form_student': form, 'user_form': user_form }
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form_students.html', {'form_student': form, 'user_form': user_form })
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a few typos you currently are setting your email variable to the email data then setting it to the password data. Correct this first.

`email = user_form.cleaned_data['email']
password = user_form.cleaned_data['password']`

Comment: yep fixed it, still issues

Comment: Are you properly importing the `StudentProfile` model?